# Postgres 'where' query is not working with PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm running some PHP code where I am trying to find rows with a specified parameter. I have successfully connected with the database, however I'm running into one problem.

When I run this code:

```
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM schema.table";
    $result = pg_exec($dbconn, $SQL);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result) {
          echo "data: " .$row . "<br/>\n";
```

I get a printed list of arrays showing that I was successful in taking this data from the database and being able to print it out into the website page.

However, I need to filter the data where I only want the rows with a specific ID. When I try this query:

```
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE 'ID' = '123'";
```

`pg_numrows($result)` is 0 when there are four rows with ID of 123 and there is nothing to show and no array and I have no idea why adding the 'where' statement changes anything. What happened to the data, why does filtering it cause it to no longer work?

---

SOLVED: Figured out the answer for anyone running into the same problem.

```
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE \"ID\" = '123'";
```

This is the syntax that must be used for character varying columns. Thanks for everyone making me realize I was running a funny code with wrong quotation marks.

Comment: Why is your ID surrounded by '', shouldn't it be 123 and not '123'?

Comment: Backticks and single-quotes and bears, oh my!

Comment: String 'ID' is never equal to string '123'.

Comment: If I don't use the single quotes on ID I get this error: Query failed: ERROR: column "id" does not exist. And when I take off single quotes from 123 I get: Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer

Comment: You could simply write: `$SQL = "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE ID = '123'";` There's no need for quoting the column name. as @user3763227 wrote in his last comment.

Answer (score 2):

use like this..

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE ID = 123";
```

Never use single quotes for column names and never use single quotes for int type..

Comment: You should explain what is wrong with the original syntax so the OP understands what the problem is.

Comment: If I don't use the single quotes on ID I get this error: Query failed: ERROR: column "id" does not exist. And when I take off single quotes from 123 I get: Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer

Comment: please provide your table structure ie, type of each column with its name

Comment: @user3756998 then try this..$SQL = "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE ID = '123'"; use single quotes for 123 only.. since you are using varchar for ID